# Определить друзей которые поставили лайк пользователю vk api, php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Здравствуйте! Вопрос следующий:

Необходимо определить друзей пользователя ВК, которые ставили ему лайк на фото.

VK API предлагает следующие подходящие для этого методы:
1) Сбор списка друзей (массив в виде ид'ов пользователей) 
2) Сбор лайков под всеми фотографиями (тоже в виде массива с ид'ами пользователей)

Вопрос:
При помощи какой операции можно определить кто из общего списка друзей, поставил лайк? 
Может сравнить эти два массива и в случае если найдены одинаковые id'ы вывести их? Но при помощи какой функции?
Жду предложений!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать запросы к обоим методам, сформировать два массива id, а затем использовать функцию array_intersect, чтобы найти id, которые есть в обоих списках.

Comment: Хорошо, а как быть с массивом из пункта "2)"? Ведь человек может лайкнуть несколько фотографий и тогда его ID будет несколько раз повторятся во втором массиве, А мне ведь еще нужно знать не только то кто лайкнул, а и сколько раз